# AHK: Trying to add a picture with transparent background over another picture in a GUI

Tags: image, overlay, autohotkey, transparent

I am trying to create a simple GUI where I add an image, then overlay another image with a transparent background over it.  Essentially, the second image just says "Loading" on top of the original one.

I've tried the code below but the "Loading" image simply places itself over the other one with a white background and completely obscures it.  If I swap the order in which GUI 1 and 2 appear, then the same problem happens but with the "Nightmare" image blocking the other one.

Any tips?

```
Gui, 1: -Caption +ToolWindow 
Gui, 1: Add, Picture, h%A_ScreenHeight% w%A_ScreenWidth% AltSubmit BackgroundTrans, D:\FrontEnd\HyperSpin\Splash Images\Loading.png
Gui, 2: -Caption +ToolWindow 
Gui, 2: Add, Picture, h%A_ScreenHeight% w%A_ScreenWidth%, D:\FrontEnd\HyperSpin\Splash Images\SC2 Nightmare.jpg
Gui, 2: Show, x-10 y-7 h%A_ScreenHeight% w%A_ScreenWidth%
Sleep, 1000
Gui, 1: Show, x-10 y-7 h%A_ScreenHeight% w%A_ScreenWidth%
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible GDIPlus may not be installed on your rig.
In any case, use [Transcolor](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinSet.htm#TransColor) instead of BackgroundTrans. It's easy if the background colour of Loading.png is one colour.

```
Gui, 1: -Caption +ToolWindow HWNDgui1Hwnd
Gui, 1: Add, Picture, h%A_ScreenHeight% w%A_ScreenWidth%, ~\Loading.png
WinSet TransColor, %hex_Background_Colour% 0, ahk_id%gui1Hwnd%
```

Or instead of an image for *Loading*, just use text, see [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#ex6).